# jq pass an array that should be converted into json array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I have script

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=("a" "b")

collection_init_msg=$( jq -n --arg arr $ARR '{arr: [$arr]}')

echo some command "$collection_init_msg"
```

that should convert the ARR and print it as a JSON array.

Current result

> some command {
> "arr": [
> "a"
> ]
> }

What I want is:

> some command {
> "arr": [
> "a", "b"
> ]
> }

Comment: `$ARR` is exactly the same as `${ARR[0]}`. You can't pass the entire array as a single value; you can only pass a single string built from the elements of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=("a" "b")

collection_init_msg=$( jq -nc '{arr: $ARGS.positional}'  --args "${ARR[@]}"  )

echo "$collection_init_msg"
```

---

In answer to the supplementary question in the comment: one could do worse than:

```
jq -n --argjson a1 $(jq -nc '$ARGS.positional' --args "${A1[@]}") '
  {$a1, a2: $ARGS.positional}' --args "${A2[@]}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to submit multiple arrays? E.g.

    #!/bin/bash
    ARR1=("a" "b")
    ARR2=("1" "2")

and have an output like

     {
     "arr1": [ "a", "b" ],
     "arr2" ["1", "2"] 
    }

Comment: @tot - See addendum.